# Eloquent query by aggregated relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to make a query by an aggregated value from the model relations.
As example I should get only *Posts* which has the last comment between two dates.

```
SELECT posts.*, MAX(comments.created_at) 
as max FROM posts 
JOIN comments ON (comments.post_id = posts.id)
GROUP BY posts.id HAVING max > '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND max < '2014-02-01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of joins use builtin methods:

```
// Assuming you have relations setup
Post::whereHas('comments', function ($q) use ($from, $till) {
   $q->groupBy('post_id')
     ->havingRaw("max(created_at) between '{$from}' and '{$till}'");
})->get();
```

It will produce:

```
select * from `posts` where 
  (select count(*) from `comments` where `comments`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id` 
    group by `post_id`
    having max(created_at) between '2014-01-01' and '2014-02-01'
  ) >= 1 limit 1
```